# Linear operator with respect to matrices? Is it natural to ask?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $T:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ be a linear operator where $E$ is some Banach (functional) space. Then for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x\in E$ one has $T(\lambda x)=\lambda T(x)$.

My question is: is it natural to consider the concept of "linear" with respect to matrices?

Let us now consider $T:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and for $f\in E$ and $A=(a_{ij})_{\substack{i=1,\dots,n\\j =1,\dots,m}}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$
$$f\ast A := (fa_{ij})_{\substack{i=1,\dots,n\\j =1,\dots,m}}.$$

Is it natural to consider operators $T$ such that for every $f\in E$ and $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ then
$$T(f\ast A)=T(f)A\quad ?$$

I was concerned that such operator is either not possible or there are very few of them. Thanks for your kind help!

Comment: What kind of object is $fa_{ij}$? It looks like it is in $E$, then $f*A \in E^{n\times m}$, but $T(f*A)$ is then not defined. Confused.

Comment: I tried to be as general as possible. I was thinking of for instance $f:\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. If a kind of Matrix linearity can be considered: for every $A,B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, one has $f(AB)=Af(B)$ but I think the only function satisfying this is a multiple of the identity.